# A view does not show inside a relative layout

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout

I have a problem with this layout and i cannot find out what is wrong.
As you can see, there is a chronometer and a table inside a relative layout but the chronometer does not show, not even a blank space.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/chrono"
    android:textColor="#4169E1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Chronometer"
/>
<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
</TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

any ideas?

Comment: make your table layout height to wrap_content

Comment: Just change position of `Chronometer` as last declaration, I mean write first `TableLayout` then `Chronometer`

Comment: thank you all for the suggestions but i believe that the problem is somewhere else, because i tried all you said and yet nothing.
I posted a new topic with the issue.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201301/view-not-showing-in-a-relative-layout-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Your `TableLayout` takes over all space (`match_parent`) and draws over the `Chronometer`. `RelativeLayout` children are laid out in order they are declared. I don't know what you want exactly, but you can start by switching the order of the two in your layout so that the `Chronometer` draws over the `TableLayout`.

Comment: what should i use in "layout_height" of the TableLayout? thanks

Answer (score 0):

First Stick `Chronometer` to bottom `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` then take `TableLayout` on above of `Chronometer`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/chrono" >
    </TableLayout>

    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/chrono"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Chronometer"
        android:textColor="#4169E1"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...this will definitly solve your problem..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/chrono"
    android:textColor="#4169E1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Chronometer"
/>

<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/chrono"
    >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

finally i got the way to display the chronometer.
Thanks to everyone who tried to help me, the answers were really close to my solution which is:

```
<Chronometer
android:id="@+id/chrono"
android:textColor="#4169E1"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:text="Chronometer"
/>
<TableLayout 
android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@id/chrono"
>
```