# View not showing in a relative layout in Android

Tags: android, layout, view, show

I posted this already but i got new information that may help you to help me...
I have a problem with this layout and i cannot find out what is wrong. As you can see, there is a chronometer and a table inside a relative layout but the chronometer does not show, not even a blank space.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/chrono"
    android:textColor="#4169E1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Chronometer"
/>
<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
</TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So i tried changing the order of the chronometer and tablelayout. I tried also changing the layout_width and layout_height properties, but i got nothing. So i went to my java class and i found out that the issue might be here:

```
 private final void createGameBoard(short gridSize) {
  DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
  getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

  TableLayout tableLayout;
  tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);    
  tableLayout.removeAllViews();

  board = GameBoard.createGameBoard(this, 
        bitmap, 
        tableLayout,
        (int) (metrics.widthPixels * metrics.density),
        (int) ((metrics.heightPixels * metrics.density)-h1),
        gridSize);
}
```

where GameBoard.createGameBoard is:

```
public static GameBoard createGameBoard(Context context, 
                             Bitmap bitmap, 
                             TableLayout parentLayout,
                             int width,
                             int height,
                             short gridSize) {

  board = new GameBoard(context, 
                   bitmap, 
                   parentLayout, 
                   width, 
                   height, 
                   gridSize);

  return board;
}
```

So i guess that the problem displaying the chronometer comes from the creation of the gameboard, because of the metrics taken from the current window, which is used to set the height of the gameboard.
any suggestions?

Comment: Your tablelayout is filling the whole relativeLayout, You set match_parent to width and height. In a relativeLayout, views are set on top of the other as long as You do not set some parameters. Try to set android:layout_below="@id/chrono" into the tableLayout. Maybe You have to change the width and height parameters from tableLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xml code:

```
<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/chrono"
    android:textColor="#4169E1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Chronometer"
/>
<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
```

This will force TableLayout to be shown in full screen and so, Chronometer is being hidden.

Try changing like one of followings:

1.)

```
<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/chrono"
    android:textColor="#4169E1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Chronometer"
/>
<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
```

Which will wrap content of table, so Chronometer will get space.

2.)

```
<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/chrono"
    android:textColor="#4169E1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Chronometer"
/>
<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/chrono"
>
```

This will force Chronometer to take full space below table layout after table layout is shown.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot, the second option finally displays the chronometer!! thankssss